# How to remove commands from SettingsPane - windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, settings

In search of how to remove the commands from the SettingsPane in Windows 8.1. I don't see it anywhere in the [SettingsPane Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingscommand.aspx) documentation in MSDN

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Add only needed commands.

In the below code , `onCommandsRequested` will be fired every time when `SettingsPane`  is opened . You can check conditions before adding commands.

```
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += onCommandsRequested;
```

Alos, close and reopen the settings pane If you want to change the command when `SettingsPane`  is open. I dont think there is other ways to achieve the same

Answer (score 1):

I found it! :) We can remove commands like this

```
void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Clear();
        // or
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.RemoveAt(0);
}
```